# Determining database relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, entity-framework, relational-database

I am adding a feature to an app where users can send and receive private chat messages to other users. (a message can only go to one user).

The user model is simple with id, name, etc. The message model will have id, title, body, senderId and receipientId.

A user can send many messages and also receive many messages, so I think this is a many to many relationship. But, a user can send many messages but each message will be sent by one user, so it could be a one to many.

How can I determine what kind of relationship this is. I have searched online about relationships and just can't figure this one out. I am using Entity Framework.

I understand basic database relationships, but this one is tricky since the use is both the sender and receiver.

Comment: Hi. Please say what information modeling & database design textbook you are following & relate what you have you done to it. Otherwise an answer just rewrites a texbook. Manuals for products recording designs are not textbooks on how to design. PS You seem interested in relation(ship)s/associations like "sender S messaged recipient R" or "message M is sender R messaging text T to recipient R". First find the entities then the relation(ship)s/associations on them. A relation(ship)/association can give an "associative entity". Then observe cardinalities according to the method you are following.

Comment: @philipxy, I appreciate the link, but that does not help me at all. I understand basic relationshops, but my question (which I made very clear) was a bit different. The one to many relationships are linking back to the same user tables so it is a bit different. I wanted clarification on the relationship and was unable to find this after searching on my own.

Comment: You need to give your reference & how you followed it. Is Message a weak entity? Then what are the relationships you want the cardinatlity of? Is it a relationship? On what entities? Which is "this" relationship? Different methods use "relationship" differently--association vs FK. Are you talking about FKs to users? It's not clear what you want to know. If you know you have FKs, what else do you need to know? Different methods determine & record cardinalities differently. Act on my first comment. See hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. PS Edit clarifications into posts, not comments.

Comment: Im not being clear yet I described my two models, it's really not that complicated. The two posters already helped me, maybe take some notes. Once again your comments are unhelpful.

Comment: Both answers start by saying you are not clear. The rest of the content of the answers validate my comments. The accepted answer re 2 FKs might help you, but it certainly doesn't answer your question, because you knew there were 2 FKs yet you were talking about some other thing, "this relationship". The 1st answer offers "relationships" in its sense of FK & the other in its other sense of association. They don't know what you want & are guessing. So I stand by my comments.

Comment: Ok. A Udemy course instructor with "20 years experience" claimed this was a many-to-many relationship because users can "send many messages and receive many messages. He doesn't respond to students so I am asking here and it turns out this is two one-to-many relationships. See my confusion now? It's hard to learn with constant conflicting info. And through my searches I did not see any examples of relationships where a single entity (users) was on both sides of the tables. But thanks for proving the general view of stack overflow being a toxic/hostile community is true.

Comment: I suggest you reread my comments because there is nothing in them that is inappropriate. They essentially say & justify that we need the method you're using & you're not clear about how you're trying to using it. I have been trying to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if I'm not understanding completely, because it seems you have answered your own question already?  There may be some confusion because you are using the terms 'user' alongside 'sender' and 'recipient.'

Senders and Recipients are all users and identified by UserID, but recipient has some different behavior than sender.  It should be treated as different element in the model.

A sender has a one-to-many relationship with a message, so the message knows who its sender is.

However, A message has a one-to many relationship with its recipients - so in typical design patterns the message doesn't know who its recipients are, rather it's the recipients who all know who their message is.  So, usually there would need to be some kind of messageRecipients mapping entity that would have messageID and recipient (Via UserID).

```
User                         Message                      MessageReceiver
--------------------         --------------------         --------------------
UserID                       MessageID                    MessageReceiverID 
UserName                     Sender (FK UserID)           Message (FK MessageID)
.                            MessageBody                  Recipient (FK UserID)
. (other fields)             .                            .
.                            . (other fields)             . (other fields)
                             .                            .
```

It may seem odd to talk about a seperate 'messageRecipient' entity when we're imagining our message entity as having the same fields as typical email or instant message editors -- these always have a place to list out recipients. But that's the gotcha.  If our data field is a list of items where we will need to work with those items individaully, then we probably need a new entity to manage them.

Anyway, that's my take on it.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, I have not seen this kind of set up before. An issue I am having learning is that every course I take seems to do things different ways. I would just assume each message has an id of the sender user and recipient user. But again I was confused how to look at this, it could be a many to many if I said "users send many messages and receive many messages", but it appears it is really two one-to-many relationships..?

Comment: I definitely see this as a pair one-to-many relationships.  That's probably not the only way to frame the problem.  For instance, what if I am a user and I have two chat windows open -- one is a group conversation with albert, betty, and chris.  But the second window is just between me and chris.  I don't want the messages he sends just to me to appear in the group chat window.  The solution described above doesn't support that distinction.  So, now do we need some kind of 'chat room' id.  A valid application, a different model

Comment: as a side note, your message entity probably should have a timestamp too.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that I understand you correctly:

`Message` has a many-to-one relationship with `user` on *senderId*.
`Message` also has a many-to-one relationship with `user` on *recipientId*.

Querying the data would look something like:

```sql
SELECT
    s.Name AS Sender
    ,r.Name AS Recipient
    ,m.Title
    ,m.Body
FROM
    Message AS m
INNER JOIN User AS s ON
    m.SenderID = s.ID
INNER JOIN User AS r ON
    m.RecipientID = r.ID
```

[Quick and dirty ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEq8f.png)

Comment: Thank you, so this isn't a many to many relationship? Or it is and it is broken down into two separate one-to-many's? I don't know why I just think "users send many messages and receive many messages" so it must be a many to many.

Comment: Added a basic ERD to help show what is happening. It's two one-to-many relationships, but slightly wonky because the user table is serving two purposes. This assumes that all senders can be recipients, and vice-versa, which appears to be true based on your given use case.

Comment: Thank you! This helps me understand greatly, was a lot easier than I thought.